# Picam java library support for Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w, picam

as Raspberry Pi Zero is based on armv6l, is it supported by Picam native library?

Using the picam on Zero I get a proper JPEG, but with all pixels black.

I wondering if there is an issue I should look for, or just the architecture is not supported.

Thanks,
Krzysztof

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a Picam with a Raspberry Pi Zero with a ribbon cable that fits into the Pi Zero. [Picam library](https://github.com/caprica/picam) should work just fine. It must be some other issue. You can look at the documentation for its configuration [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/camera.md). Make sure you follow the steps properly.

Some other links:

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md
- https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera